# How to concatenate input into URL for href

Tags: vba, outlook, hyperlink, html-email

I am looking to get inputs from the user and flash-fill an email. The inputs being ID numbers I want to concatenate to the end of a static URL and link in the body of the email.

What I have so far:

```vb
Sub Release()
Dim objMsg As MailItem
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim Obj1 As String
Obj1 = InputBox("Enter ID1", "Input Number Only"
If Obj1 <> ""
    With objMsg
        strEmailBody = "Hello ___" & "Object #" & Obj1 & "<a href=""http://....id=""&Obj1>(link)</a>"
        .HTMLBody = strEmailBody`
```

Everything seems to perform except the link, which is the static URL and does not concatenate the input number.

I tried changing around the quotation marks and changing the whole URL to a variable, but I cannot get more than just the string as typed to appear in the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need to concatenate strings in VBA correctly:

```
strEmailBody = "Hello ___" & "Object #" & Obj1 & "<a href=" & Chr(34) &"http://....id=" & Obj1 & Chr(34) & ">(link)</a>"
```

Note, you can use the [Chr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function) for inserting double quotes where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
strEmailBody = "Hello ___" & "Object #" & Obj1 & _
               "<a href=""http://....id=" & Obj1 & """>(link)</a>"
```

or a little simpler using single quotes for the href attribute value:

```vb
strEmailBody = "Hello ___" & "Object #" & Obj1 & _
               "<a href='http://....id=" & Obj1 & "'>(link)</a>"
```